# Total probability of an event

Tags: statistics, probability

We have an application where we're trying to quantify the total risk(hitting traffic, say) of a trip in a car where probability is a function of time and a series of algorithms:

[image: Our probability graph with error bars]

How can we quantify the 'total' risk of the trip while respecting the amount of time the car is exposed to higher risk?  My gut says it's a matter of an integral but my stats isn't strong in the least and think I might be missing something obvious.

EDIT:

The y-axis is the probability that an event occurs and the x-axis the time elapsed, in minutes.

Comment: You should ask this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In addition to being off-topic, your plot doesn't make sense because it is not clear what is on y-axis. There should be a probability density I guess. If it is a probability of some event over a period of time, it should always have a positive slope.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll post it over at cross validated.

Comment: @Refefer Well, I don't see how the probability of hitting traffic can possibly be smaller if you travel for 100 minutes than for 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the function you have show is what's called a hazard function, that is, the probability of an event at a given time, assuming that there has been no event before that time. The survival function, i.e., probability that there is no event before a given time, is equal to `exp(-H(t))` where `H(t)` is the so-called cumulative hazard function, `H(t) = integral(h(u), u, 0, t)` where `h(t)` is the hazard function. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis